# Shiny plotly render issue with lines rstudio

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have an issue with plotly rendering in shiny app:

[image]

As you can see in the picture ; the lines (from layout/shapes in my plot construction) don't go to the right end of the plot (the lines' title (from `add_annotation`) are not well placed too.

There is my code for plot construction :

```
plotXbarD<-plot_ly(
  data = triBOE(),
  x=~titre
)

plotXbarD <- plotXbarD %>%
   add_trace(y=triBOE()$Drying.Analysis.Crush.Strenght.Mean,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',marker=list(color="red"))
plotXbarD<-plotXbarD %>%
   layout(xaxis = list( title= "",tickangle = 45,tickfont=list(size=10)),
                                    shapes=list(
                                      list(type='line', x0=min(triBOE()$titre) , x1=max(triBOE()$titre) , y0=DlscM(),
                                           y1=DlscM(), line=list(dash='dash', width=2,color='red')),

                                      list(type='line', x0=min(triBOE()$titre) , x1=max(triBOE()$titre) , y0=DcibleM(),
                                           y1=DcibleM(), line=list(dash='dash', width=2,color='green')),

                                      list(type='line', x0=min(triBOE()$titre) , x1=max(triBOE()$titre) , y0=DlicM(),
                                           y1=DlicM(), line=list(dash='dash', width=2,color='red'))
                                    )
)

plotXbarD <- plotXbarD %>% add_annotations(
  x=max(triBOE()$titre),
  y=DlscM(),
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y",
  text = "limite superieure",
  xanchor = 'left',
  showarrow = F
)

plotXbarD <- plotXbarD %>% add_annotations(
  x=max(triBOE()$titre),
  y=DcibleM(),
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y",
  text = "Cible",
  xanchor = 'left',
  showarrow = F
)
plotXbarD <- plotXbarD %>% add_annotations(
  x=max(triBOE()$titre),
  y=DlicM(),
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y",
  text = "limite inferieur",
  xanchor = 'left',
  showarrow = F
)

})
```

When I run this in rstudio there is no problem with render; but in shiny this going wrong!!

Is it a good thing to use plotly in shiny or is it better to use renderplotly with ggplot construction?

There is an data exemple

PO.Label ;Drying.Batch.Name ;Drying.Start.Time.1 ;Drying.Analysis.Crush.Strenght.Mean ;Drying.Analysis.Crush.Strenght.Std.Deviation ;Drying.Analysis.Elasticity.Mean ;Drying.Analysis.Elasticity.Std.Deviation
1236675;B37-40;2018/06/26 13:14:37;1.40;0.11;43.89;1.79
1245515;B41-44;2018/06/26 06:14:55;1.34;0.20;42.79;3.40
1245515;B41-44;2018/06/26 06:14:55;1.24;0.25;39.75;4.06
1245765;B05-08;2018/06/26 05:28:56;1.37;0.25;40.95;3.71
1245529;B01-06;2018/06/24 12:47:27;1.56;0.39;42.86;4.94
1240251;B33-36;2018/06/26 15:59:08;1.10;0.48;37.22;6.26
1236675;B41-44;2018/06/26 16:16:34;1.48;0.40;43.49;6.04
1240180;B43-48;2018/06/26 00:19:07;1.90;0.26;42.19;4.87
1245765;B13-16;2018/06/26 07:56:17;1.33;0.21;40.71;3.47

I adding an « titre » column by pasting ID/Drying start time/po label/driying batch name

Comment: Hi Ludo, could you provide an example of your data?

Comment: Hi Phil there is an exemple PO.Label ;Drying.Batch.Name ;Drying.Start.Time.1 ;Drying.Analysis.Crush.Strenght.Mean ;Drying.Analysis.Crush.Strenght.Std.Deviation ;Drying.Analysis.Elasticity.Mean ;Drying.Analysis.Elasticity.Std.Deviation
1236675;B37-40;2018/06/26 13:14:37;1.40;0.11;43.89;1.79
1245515;B41-44;2018/06/26 06:14:55;1.34;0.20;42.79;3.40
1245515;B41-44;2018/06/26 06:14:55;1.24;0.25;39.75;4.06
1245765;B05-08;2018/06/26 05:28:56;1.37;0.25;40.95;3.71
1245529;B01-06;2018/06/24 12:47:27;1.56;0.39;42.86;4.94
1240251;B33-36;2018/06/26 15:59:08;1.10;0.48;37.22;6.26
Adding a titre column